# What is causing this CSS Transition delay, specifically with colours in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Using CSS transitions on most properties runs as expected, except this issue I am having with colours.

I have set up a demonstration pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqqLby).

When transitions are instructed to change the color property, they all queue after each other instead of happening all at once.

This seems limited to webkit as IE and Firefox work as expected.

```
#change {
    color: green;
    transition: color 200ms linear;
}
.changed {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because `color` is inherited property, and you use `*` selector for `transition`. You should set `transition: color` only to element you change `color`, for example (http://codepen.io/sergdenisov/pen/QbjjjP):

```
#container {
    padding: 0;
    transition: color 500ms;
}
#container * {
    transition: margin 500ms;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This has solved it. Unfortunately, I now have to list every property I want to transition. If I try to use *, this happens for all inherited properties.